Unable to Access GitLab Web Interface, but curl Inside the Container Returns 200 OK
I am facing an issue with my GitLab setup. When I run curl inside the GitLab container, I get a 200 OK response, but I can't access the same URL from the web interface or my host machine. Below is a detailed description of my setup and the problem I’m encountering.
Setup Details:
GitLab Running in a Docker Container:
I am using the GitLab container named gitlab2.
The service is supposed to be accessible on http://mon-gitlab.local:8081.
Curl Test Inside the Container:
When I execute the following command inside the GitLab container:
curl -I http://mon-gitlab.local:8081/users/sign_in

I get a successful 200 OK response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2024 23:19:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Etag: W/"780e2667bc65c3c664fa06a82ea15027"
Set-Cookie: preferred_language=en; path=/

Set-Cookie: _gitlab_session=8da14b74018d05edbec6794338f2b8aa; path=/; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
Accessing from Host or Web Interface Fails:
However, when I try to access the same URL from my host machine or browser (http://mon-gitlab.local:8081), I encounter a "Connection Refused" error:
curl -I http://mon-gitlab.local:8081/users/sign_in
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mon-gitlab.local port 8081: Connection refused

Similarly, accessing the web interface in a browser also results in the same issue.

I think you need to check two things: first one did you exposed 8081 from your container? And second one - you need to check your firewall settings.

@nmishin,  sarra@worker10:~$ docker exec -it gitlab bash
root@mon-gitlab:/# netstat -tuln | grep 8081
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
root@mon-gitlab:/#

no firewall in my network

you need to check netstat from your host, not from the docker container,
did you run it with --expose 8081 or you expose port somehow?
can you show me your command for docker run?
